# This seems to be a bug in the clang++ compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, clang++

The following code executes normally (see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ffd09f586786d63)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i;
    A():i(1){}
    operator int&() { return i; }
};

int& rri = A();

int main()
{
    int& ri = A();
    std::cout << ri << '\n';
    std::cout << rri << '\n';
}
```

It prints

```
1
1
```

as expected. However if I comment out the first two statements in main(), leaving just

```
std::cout << rri << '\n';
```

the code prints `0`.

**Edit:**

Let's assume the problem is with my code. But then I ask: what is the purpose of the third  bullet point in 8.5.3/5 in the Standard, which I copied below:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type
>   “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>   - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” or
>   - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an lvalue of type
>       “cv3 T3,” where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3” (this conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion functions (13.3.1.6) and choosing the best one through
>       overload resolution (13.3)),
>
>   then the reference is bound to the
>     initializer expression lvalue in the first case and to the lvalue
>     result of the conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to
>     the appropriate base class subobject of the object). [ Note: The usual
>     lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and
>     function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are not needed, and
>     therefore are suppressed, when such direct bindings to lvalues are
>     done. —end note ]

Comment: Rule of thumb: The bug isn't in the compiler, it's in your understanding of the language.

Comment: That program is undefined.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, that's what I meant. I'll edit the comment.

Comment: -1:  This is not a bug in the compiler.  It's a bug in your code.

Comment: When you use widely used compiler (like MS', gcc, clang, etc), I'd advise you to _always_ think the problem is in your code, rather than in the compiler's. Compiler bugs are incredibly rare (especially for stable versions) and most probably 99.99% of the questions here, suggesting "compiler bug" appear to be bug in the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Undefined behaviour: `ri` and `rri` are both initialised to refer to a member of a temporary, which is immediately destroyed.

The dangling reference points to some bit of memory which might be reused by another object, in which case you might see data from that object. Or you might see some other kind of undefined behaviour.

Comment: What if the global reference were const, e.g.: `int const& rri = A();` ?

Comment: Nope. Still not valid.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Still the same. The lifetime of a temporary is only extended if the reference is initialised directly with the temporary. Here, it's initialised with the result of `operator int&()`, so the temporary is destroyed at the end of the expression.

Comment: The object referred by rri is imediately destroyed, but the one referred by ri is not. Can you explain?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: Both are immediately destroyed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Doesn't `rri` extend the lifetime of the temporary to the end of the program?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: Only if the reference is directly bound to the temporary (and only if the reference is `const`). Here, it's bound to the result of `operator int&()`, not to the temporary `A`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Then, what is the purpose of the second bullet point, of the first bullet point in 8.5.3/5 in the Standard?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil `int& ri = A();` is actually saying `int& ri = (int&)A();`.  This, in effect, is a reference to a temporary copy.  It is not binding to the object produced from `A()`, but rather the internal reference to `i`.  Since the result from `A()` is not bound to anything, it is destroyed, and thus, `i` is destroyed with it.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: That bullet point describes how the reference is initialised. The following paragraph clarifies that "the reference is bound ... to the lvalue result of the conversion" - not to the temporary.

Comment: @ZacHowland Why would the standard even bother to consider this possibility, as described in the third bullet point in 8.5.3/5?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil From that section:  `int& ir = B(); // ir refers to the result of B::operator int&` - which is exactly what happens.  However, in the OP's case, the result of `B::operator int&` is a reference to a member variable of a temporary object created by `B()`, that is not bound to anything.  When the result of `B()` is destroyed, its internal data members are also destroyed (meaning the reference is an alias for a data element that no longer exists).

Comment: @ZacHowland How come the code here (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad2013cd9db8d921) seems to work correctly? In other words, why the temporary objects that initialized `ri` and `rri` were not destroyed in this case?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: They were destroyed. If you print something from the destructor, you'll see that before the rest of the output. It only "seems" to work because the memory either hasn't been reused, or has been reused by another object writing the value 1 into the same place.

Comment: @ZacHowland `From that section: int& ir = B(); // ir refers to the result of B::operator int& - which is exactly what happens.` What is the purpose of this construction, if `ir`will be undefined just after this statement.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: The conversion doesn't necessarily give a reference to a member of the temporary, so the behaviour isn't necessarily undefined (although it is in the example you gave).

Comment: @WakeupBrazil In the example they give in the standard document, it does not specify what `operator int&` is doing.  The whole purpose of that section is to show you how the reference is initialized (not talk about its lifetime).  While your code looks similar, the devil is in the details.  For example, if `int i` was instead `static int i`, it is no longer UB.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Now I think I finally understood. This all happened because I was thinking that the above mentioned bullet point would be an exception to the rule that a non-const lvalue reference doesn't bind to a temporary. But from what you're saying this rule prevails even in this case. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @MikeSeymour (+1) for this great answer.

Comment: @ZacHowland Your suggestion about the `static int i` was also great. Everything is clear now. Thanks.